# I can´t figure out whats wrong with my if statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a if statement, it should redirect visitors if they dont come from facebook, facebook mobile or instagram.

```
    $ref            =   $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    $facebook       =   "https://www.facebook.com/";
    $facemob        =   "https://www.m.facebook.com/";
    $instagram      =   "https://www.instagram.com/";

    if ($ref != $facebook or $ref != $facemob or $ref != $instagram) {
        echo "my header location here../ you are not welcome";
    } else{
     echo "Welcome!";
    }
    ?>
```

It works just fine if i only use `if($ref != $facebook) {...`ofcause only if i come from a facebook ref. :)

Comment: Use `and` instead of `or`?

Comment: side note `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is unreliable (and i hate facebook)

Comment: $ref will always match at least 2 of those 3 statements.  if its facebook, its not facemob and its not instagram.  if its facemob its not facebook and not instagram. if its instagram, its not facemob, and its not facebook. if its google, its not facebook,facemob or instagram...

Comment: The condition will never we true, since referer can't be all those three urls at once. Also I believe that the http referer header contains the full url of the refering page. So you might have to extract the domain name from the string before checking.

Answer (score 0):

Your `If` statement makes no sense. It's always going through. Even if `$ref==$facebook`, it means that `$ref!=$instagram`for example. Which means that it will never go through the `else` statement. It cant be all of them, but to go through the `else` statement, `$ref` has to be equal to `$facebook`,`$instagram` and `$facemob`. Which is not possible. You're looking for `AND` instead of `OR`.